# Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavenCentral()'

Tags: java, gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "s3://$s3_bucket"
            authentication {
                awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace.startsWith('com.microservice')) {
                useVersion "1.5.x"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Could not find method mavenCentral() for arguments [] on object of
>   type
>   org.gradle.plugin.repository.internal.DefaultPluginRepositoriesSpec.

in `settings.gradle` file. getting the error like above, how to fix this?

Comment: You're probably using an outdated versin of gradle: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3169

Comment: yes, changed to 4.7 version, fixed the issue, thanks.